# How can I add and view other AD LDAP attributes in a WAS v8.0 federated repository's LDAP repository?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, security, websphere-8

Within WebSphere Application Server v8.0.0.5, I've set up a Security Domain.  Within that Security Domain, I've created a federated repository consisting of:

```
- an LDAP repository
- a JDBC Custom User Registry that's read-only (uses a Registry Bridge)
```

I've been able to get both repos created and configured, and I can display users via the "Manage users" button.  I can't figure out how to create AND THEN view/confirm a new LDAP repo property named "title" and map it to an existing LDAP attribute also named "title".  I'm expecting to be able to see this "title" property when viewing my list of users from the federated repo within my domain.  I've followed the steps outlined here:
http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=matt&product=was-base-dist&topic=twim_ldap_attributes

Since "title" is an existing LDAP attribute, I specified it as "supported" and assigned it to the PersonAccount EntityType.

Once I restart WAS, navigate to my domain, and click on "Manage users", I don't see the "title" property listed.  I only see User ID, First Name, Last Name, E-mail, and Unique Name columns listed.  How can I view the "title" property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My expectations were unfeasible.  You can't view LDAP attributes such as "title" within the WAS admin console via "Manage users".

Ultimately, my question was resolved by realizing that I could specify Search bases and filters, which allowed me to retrieve the exact user base and groups that I wanted.